# Unit Test - Null Reference Exc

Tags: c#, class, unit-testing

I get NullReferenceException when I try to test my class and I have no idea why?
Exeption is connected to: **o1.Products.Add**.
When I try to delete it, everything is ok.

```
public class Product
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public decimal Value { get; set; }
}

public class Order
{
    public List<Product> Products { get; set; }

    private decimal value { get; set; }
    public decimal Value
    {
        get { return value; }
        set
        {
            if (Products.Count == 0)
                value = 0;
            else
                value = Products.Sum(x => Convert.ToInt32(x));
        }
    }
}

[TestClass]
public class Tests
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void OrderTest()
    {
        //Arrange
        Product p1 = new Product();
        Order o1 = new Order();
        //Act
        p1.Value = 10;
        o1.Products.Add(p1);
        //Assert
        Assert.AreEqual(30, o1.Value);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because `Products` is never instantiated, so it is `null` - you are calling `null.Add(p1)`, which is a **null reference**.

To fix it, you can create an `Order` constructor and instantiate `Products` there.

```
public class Order
{
    public List<Product> Products { get; set; }

    public Order() {
        this.Products = new List<Product>();
    }
}
```

Comment: Downvoter: Why was this answer downvoted? It seems to have been downvoted at the same time as the question. If you feel that the question is a bad question, that does not necessarily mean that my answer is a bad answer. Please vote answers on their own merit.

Comment: Thanks! It's realy great answer!